# How to create a progressive pie chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, gauge

I want to create a progressive Piechart like the image below using Highcharts. I know to create basic Highcharts, but have limited experience customizing Highcharts for advanced charts. Your guidance to approach my case is highly appreciated. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple overlapping pie series with data labels. Example:

```
const total = 69;
const target = 10;
const complete = 10;
const remaining = 59;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            colorByPoint: false,
            color: 'transparent',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                distance: -30,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Math.round(this.y * 100 / total) + '%';
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: 20
                }
            },
            size: '80%'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'green',
        data: [{
                y: complete,
                color: 'green',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            remaining
        ],
        innerSize: '40%'
    }, {
        data: [
            complete,
            {
                y: 1,
                color: 'red'
            },
            remaining - 1
        ]
    }, {
        size: '10%',
        color: 'red',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        data: [target]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lnxd9a45/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me greatly to solve my issue.